# Which file extension can be used to store data in the form of key=value for AWS ECS configuration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

Creating a Python(boto3) script to `register_task_definition` and `create_service`. It has the following syntax for `create_service`:

```
create_service = client.create_service(
   cluster = cluster_name,
   serviceName = env+"-"+client_name+"-service",
   taskDefinition = <task-defination-arn>,
   launchType = "FARGATE",
   desiredCount = 1,
   platformVersion = "1.3.0",
   networkConfiguration={
          'awsvpcConfiguration': {
          'subnets': ["subnet-00000000000000","subnet-00000000000000"],
          'securityGroups': ["sg-00000000000000"],
          'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
          }
   })
```

Here I don't want to keep my `register_task_definition` or `create_service` configuration in the code(content of create_service() function) and want to pull it from some template file.

Question are:

1. What is the best approach to do the same
2. What file extension I should use to save the configuration file eg: `register_task_definition.json`

Comment: Any reason you're not using CDK for provisioning?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `json` is a good way. So you would have to store all these parameters in a **json file**:

```
{
    "cluster": "cluster_name",
    "serviceName": "service_name",
    "taskDefinition": "<task-defination-arn>",
    "launchType": "FARGATE",
    "desiredCount": 1,
    "platformVersion": "1.3.0",
    "networkConfiguration": {
        "awsvpcConfiguration": {
            "subnets": ["subnet-00000000000000", "subnet-00000000000000"],
            "securityGroups": ["sg-00000000000000"],
            "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
        }
    }
}
```

then load to python:

```
with open('./service.json', 'r') as f:
  service_details = json.load(f)

service_details["serviceName"] = env+"-"+client_name+"-service"

create_service = client.create_service(**service_details)
```